# Botón conmutador

Tags: android

Quiero que al pulsar un botón abra y cierre un layout, pero parece que no funciona. Creo que es porque instancio el layout dentro del mismo método, pero si lo defino fuera me da error null object reference

```
    public boolean inv_open = false;        

    private void inventario (View view){
        FrameLayout vista = findViewById(R.id.idVista);
        LinearLayout inventario = new LinearLayout(this);
        TextView nombre = new TextView(this);
        nombre.setText("Articulos");

        if (inv_open){
            vista.removeView(inventario);
            inv_open = false;
            return;
        }
        else{
            vista.addView(inventario);
            inventario.addView(nombre);
            inv_open = true;
       }
}
```

Comment: estas definiendo :  LinearLayout inventario = new LinearLayout(this); pero de cualquier forma que deseas cargar en el Layout?

Comment: Añado el TextView nombre.

Answer (score -1):

Define una variable a nivel de clase, de esta forma puedes remover y agregar la instancia sin problema:

```
 public boolean inv_open = false;
 private LinearLayout inventario; //* Aquí!

    private void inventario (View view){
        FrameLayout vista = findViewById(R.id.idVista);

        inventario = new LinearLayout(this); //*Almacena el valor en la variable.

        TextView nombre = new TextView(this);
        nombre.setText("Articulos");

        if (inv_open){
            vista.removeView(inventario);
            inv_open = false;
            return;
        }
        else{
            vista.addView(inventario);
            inventario.addView(nombre);
            inv_open = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, no destruye el layout.

Comment: Creo que el problema sigue siendo que creo una nueva instancia de inventario, por eso el removeView no destruye el layout que se esta mostrando.